# Unit snap-core-716.mount has failed on Ubuntu 16.04 lts (rootfs) armhf

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap, arm, squashfs

I have Ubuntu 16.04 lts (rootfs) running on an armhf kernel.

I have an issue when I try to install snaps with errors Unit snap-core-716.mount has failed as per hereunder:

An example of a snap install - no snaps worked so far...

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo snap install nextcloud
[sudo] password for user:
error: cannot perform the following tasks:
- Mount snap "core" (716) ([start snap-core-716.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-716.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-716.mount" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
)
user@hostname:~$
```

Output of sudo systemctl status snap-core-716.mount

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo systemctl status snap-core-716.mount
● snap-core-716.mount - Mount unit for core
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/snap-core-716.mount; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2017-01-09 10:48:00 UTC; 1min 53s ago
    Where: /snap/core/716
     What: /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_716.snap
  Process: 4977 ExecMount=/bin/mount /var/lib/snapd/snaps/core_716.snap /snap/core/716 -t squashfs (code=exited, status=32)

Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: Mounting Mount unit for core...
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname mount[4977]: mount: unknown filesystem type 'squashfs'
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-716.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for core.
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-716.mount: Unit entered failed state.
user@hostname:~$
```

Output of journalctl -xe

```
user@hostname:~$ sudo journalctl -xe
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-716.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=32
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: Failed to mount Mount unit for core.
-- Subject: Unit snap-core-716.mount has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit snap-core-716.mount has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname systemd[1]: snap-core-716.mount: Unit entered failed state.
Jan 09 10:48:00 hostname /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[2442]: task.go:303: DEBUG: 2017-01-09T10:48:00Z ERROR [start snap-core-716.mount] failed with exit status 1: Job for snap-core-716.mount failed. See "systemctl status snap-core-716.mount" and
Jan 09 10:48:01 hostname /usr/lib/snapd/snapd[2442]: taskrunner.go:353: DEBUG: Running task 61 on Undo: Download snap "core" (716) from channel "stable"
........
log file: nap-core-716.mount has failed
```

How can this be solved?

Comment: Are you saying this is a chroot, then? I don't believe snaps run in chroots.

Comment: Have no idea that is why I asked. Seems a squashfs issue to me.

Comment: Is this an Ubuntu kernel, or a custom one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While googling in order to find a quick solution to this error message, that `chroot` comment reminded me that I already faced this problem some months ago.

Well, back then there was an **unresolved issue** with `snapd` and something related to **linux containers** (CT/lxc/whatever). *Feel free to look for a proper answer since I just won't do it again.*

As I was messing with a DS w/ proxmox on it this is what I did:

---

## **THE SOLUTION**: `Use KVM instead of CT`

---

But right now, as I was just looking for the quickest way to install [Micro](https://micro-editor.github.io/), in which I totally failed as ending up here means just the opposite, I'll **just download the precompiled binaries instead**.

So long and thanks to all those writing a **BIG TL;DR** in above their curated
answers to places like this. *(btw, when spotting one of those great TL;DR, give it an upvote for the sake of all us and you too in the future if u happen to look for an answer that you already knew, u might find it on 1st place in the search results next time).

### GL!